# Animations Slow As Window Size Increases

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I've started to build a Wpf app by re-templating the chrome of the main window. My chrome template contains 4 buttons which each have a template that displays a border with an image inside and uses a trigger and colour animation to re-colour the border to provide a mouse over effect. The rest of the template is static and the content of the window is a button (just to display something). I do have AllowTransparency set to True.

The problem I've got is when the window is small (say 800w x 500h) the animations run fine, they start the moment the mouse enters and play at the correct speed but as I make the window larger the animations slow down and there starting lags the mouse entering the button until the window is maximized where you have to leave the mouse sitting over the button for a period of time before the animation plays and when it does its very jerky and slow.

I have tried the following to track down this issue but to no avail:

- Made sure that only the xaml animations were playing no vb or other event handlers were being executed at the same time.
- Defined Height, Width, and ZIndex values on the containing StackPanel so hopefully?? wpf would only redraw the StackPanel contents.
- Removed 3 of the 4 buttons.
- Tried it on different screens (which use different graphics cards).
- Reconfigured my system so it only used one screen.
- Made sure hardware acceleration was on.
- Ran Resource Monitor and noticed that when the window is small constantly mousing across the buttons uses about 2% of my cpu resources but when the window is maximized is uses about 23%.

I'm guessing that wpf is redrawing a lot more than I expect but I don't know how to stop that if that is the case.

Any help would be very much welcomed.
Sorry for the huge list of Xaml.

**Window:**

```
<Window x:Class="Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"


        WindowState="{Binding ShellState,
                              Mode=OneWayToSource}"

        Title="{Binding Title,
                        Mode=OneTime}"

        Style="{Binding ShellStyling,
                        Mode=OneTime}"

        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"><!-- ShellStyling = MainWindowShellStyle-->

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="{Binding TitleHeight,
                                              Mode=OneTime}"

                      ResizeBorderThickness="{Binding ResizeBorderThickness,
                                                      Mode=OneTime}"
                      GlassFrameThickness="0"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <ContentControl Name="Stage"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Styles:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key = "ChromeButtonBaseStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property = "Template"
                Value = "{StaticResource MizedButtonTemplate}"/>

        <Setter Property = "WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.Placement"
                Value = "Bottom"/>

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "VerticalAlignment"
                Value = "Bottom"/>

        <Setter Property = "HorizontalAlignment"
                Value = "Center"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ChromeButtonImageBaseStyle"
           TargetType = "Image">

        <Setter Property = "SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.Placement"
                Value = "Bottom"/>

        <Setter Property = "Stretch"
                Value = "None"/>

        <Setter Property = "RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode"
                Value = "NearestNeighbor"/>

        <Setter Property = "WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome"
                Value = "True"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ChromeButtonImageStyle"
           TargetType = "Image"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource ChromeButtonImageBaseStyle}">

        <Setter Property = "Height"
                Value = "{Binding ImageHeight,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Width"
                Value = "{Binding ImageWidth,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ChromeButtonsContainerStyle"
           TargetType = "Border">

        <Setter Property = "Background"
                Value = "{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>

    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ChromeButtonsInnerContainerStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type StackPanel}">

        <Setter Property = "Orientation"
                Value = "Horizontal"/>

        <Setter Property = "VerticalAlignment"
                Value = "Bottom"/>

    </Style>


    <Style TargetType = "{x:Type Button}"
           x:Key = "ChromeButtonStyle"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource ChromeButtonBaseStyle}">

        <Setter Property = "Border.CornerRadius"
                Value = "{Binding CornerRadius,
                                  Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Padding"
                Value = "{Binding ImagePadding,
                                  Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Margin"
                Value = "{Binding ImageMargin,
                                  Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.VerticalOffset"
                Value = "{Binding ToolTipVerticalOffset,
                                  Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset"
                Value = "{Binding ToolTipHorizontalOffset,
                              Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType = "{x:Type Button}"
           x:Key = "CloseButtonStyle"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource ChromeButtonStyle}">


        <Setter Property = "Template"
                Value = "{StaticResource CloseButtonTemplate}"/>


        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.ToolTip"
                Value = "{Binding ToolTipText}"/>

        <EventSetter Event = "Click"
                     Handler = "HandleCloseWindow" />
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ContainerGridStyle"
           TargetType = "Grid">

        <Setter Property = "Background"
                Value = "Transparent"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "ContentContainerStyle"
           TargetType = "Border">

        <Setter Property = "Background"
                Value = "{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "GripHandleStyle"
           TargetType = "Image">

        <Setter Property = "Width"
                Value = "{Binding GripHandleWidth,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Height"
                Value = "{Binding TitleHeight,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Stretch"
                Value = "None"/>

        <Setter Property = "SnapsToDevicePixels"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "Margin"
                Value = "0"/>

        <Setter Property = "HorizontalAlignment"
                Value = "Right"/>

        <Setter Property = "Source"
                Value = "{Binding GripHandleDefinition,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode"
                Value = "NearestNeighbor"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "InnerBorderStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type Border}">

        <Setter Property = "Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth = "0"
                                  BlurRadius = "8"
                                  RenderingBias = "Quality"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "MaximizeButtonStyle"
           TargetType = "Button"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource ChromeButtonStyle}">

        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.ToolTip"
                Value = "{Binding ToolTipText}"/>


        <EventSetter Event = "Click"
                     Handler = "HandleMaximizeWindow"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "MinimizeButtonStyle"
           TargetType = "Button"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource ChromeButtonStyle}">


        <Setter Property = "ToolTipService.ToolTip"
                Value = "{Binding ToolTipText}"/>


        <EventSetter Event = "Click"
                     Handler = "HandleMinimizeWindow"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "OuterBorderStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type Border}">

        <Setter Property = "BorderThickness"
                Value = "0"/>

        <Setter Property = "BorderBrush"
                Value = "{x:Null}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Background"
                Value = "Transparent"/>

        <Setter Property = "Padding"
                Value = "{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                Path=DataContext.OuterMarginThickness,
                                Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "TitleLayoutStyle"
           TargetType = "StackPanel">

        <Setter Property = "Orientation"
                Value = "Horizontal"/>

        <Setter Property = "Height"
                Value = "{Binding TitleHeight,
                                Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "TitleTextBaseStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type TextBlock}">

        <Setter Property = "FontFamily"
                Value = "Segoe UI"/>

        <Setter Property = "Foreground"
                Value = "{StaticResource TitleBrush}"/>

        <Setter Property = "VerticalAlignment"
                Value = "Bottom"/>

        <Setter Property = "Background"
                Value = "Transparent"/>

        <Setter Property = "Text"
                Value = "{Binding Title,
                              Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "TitleTextStyle"
           TargetType = "TextBlock"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource TitleTextBaseStyle}">

        <Setter Property = "FontSize"
                Value = "{Binding TitleTextFontSize,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Margin"
                Value = "{Binding TitleTextMargin,
                          Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "WindowShellBaseStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type Window}">

        <Setter Property = "OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value = "True"/>

        <Setter Property = "WindowStyle"
                Value = "None"/>

        <Setter Property = "AllowsTransparency"
                Value = "True"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key = "MainWindowShellStyle"
           TargetType = "{x:Type Window}"
           BasedOn = "{StaticResource WindowShellBaseStyle}">

        <Setter Property = "Height"
                Value = "{Binding Height}"/>

        <Setter Property = "Width"
                Value = "{Binding Width}"/>

        <Setter Property = "MaxHeight"
                Value = "{Binding MaxHeight}"/>

        <Setter Property = "MaxWidth"
                Value = "{Binding MaxWidth}"/>

        <Setter Property = "MinHeight"
                Value = "{Binding MinHeight}"/>

        <Setter Property = "MinWidth"
                Value = "{Binding MinWidth}"/>

        <Setter Property = "ShowInTaskbar"
                Value = "{Binding ShowInTaskBar}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Templates:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary
            Source = "pack://application:,,,/WindowChromeColors.xaml"/>

        <ResourceDictionary
            Source = "pack://application:,,,/WindowChromeAnimations.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


    <ControlTemplate TargetType = "{x:Type Button}"
                     x:Key = "CloseButtonTemplate">

        <Border Padding = "{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Margin = "{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                BorderThickness = "{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius = "{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels = "True">

            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name = "HoverBorderColor"
                                 Color = "{StaticResource MouseOutBorder}"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>

            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name = "ButtonBackground"
                                 Color = "{StaticResource Background}"/>
            </Border.Background>

            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                   Style="{Binding ImageStyle}" />
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent = "MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName = "HoverBorderColor">
                        <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType -->
                        <StaticResource ResourceKey = "HoverBorderAnimation"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>

                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName = "ButtonBackground">
                        <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType -->
                        <StaticResource ResourceKey = "CloseButtonHoverBgAnimation"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent = "MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName = "HoverBorderColor">
                            <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType -->
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey = "LeaveBorderAnimation"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName = "ButtonBackground">
                            <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType -->
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey = "CloseButtonLeaveBgAnimation"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>



    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
                     x:Key="MizedButtonTemplate">

        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Border.CornerRadius}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"
>

            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="HoverBorderColor"
                                 Color="{StaticResource MouseOutBorder}" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>

            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                   Style="{Binding ImageStyle}"/>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="HoverBorderColor">
                         <!--ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType--> 
                        <StaticResource ResourceKey="HoverBorderAnimation" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="HoverBorderColor">
                         <!--ReSharper disable once Xaml.InvalidResourceType--> 
                        <StaticResource ResourceKey="LeaveBorderAnimation" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowShellTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type Window}">


        <Border Style="{StaticResource OuterBorderStyle}">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource InnerBorderStyle}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Style="{StaticResource ContainerGridStyle}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Style="{StaticResource GripHandleStyle}"/>


                        <Border Grid.Column="2"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Style="{StaticResource ChromeButtonsContainerStyle}">

                            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ChromeButtonsInnerContainerStyle}">

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" />


                                <Button DataContext="{Binding MinimizeButtonViewModel,
                                                              Mode=OneTime}"

                                        Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButtonStyle}"

                                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility,
                                                             Mode=OneTime}"
                                        Tag = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                      Mode=OneTime}" />


                                <Button DataContext="{Binding MaximizeButtonViewModel,
                                                              Mode=OneTime}"

                                        Style="{StaticResource MaximizeButtonStyle}"

                                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility,
                                                             Mode=OneTime}"
                                        Tag = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                      Mode=OneTime}" />


                                <Button DataContext="{Binding CloseButtonViewModel,
                                                              Mode=OneTime}"

                                        Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}"

                                        Visibility="{Binding Visibility,
                                                             Mode=OneTime}"

                                        Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                      Mode=OneWay}"

                                        Command = "{Binding ClickAction,
                                                            Mode=OneTime}"

                                        CommandParameter = "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                                                    AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                                     Mode=OneTime}" />

                            </StackPanel>

                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Style="{StaticResource ContentContainerStyle}">

                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Animations** All the colour animations are the same as the one below they just animate different colours.

```
<ColorAnimation x:Key="HoverBorderAnimation"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                To="{StaticResource MouseHoverBorder}"
                Duration="0:0:0.25"
                AutoReverse="False" />
```

Comment: Any chance to provide a minimal example to reproduce this? At first glance it looks unbelievable that Window size makes such a huge difference.

Comment: We'd have to see an example to troubleshoot. I see mention of `StackPanel` which could lead to layout issues on measure()/arrange() but only way to find the culprit(s) would be to see something.

Comment: Or you can remove the irrelevant code from your project, and upload the whole project to GitHub, make sure it can be compiled before uploaded. It is quite hard to build a running project from the code you posted...still some definitions are missing.

Comment: Out of curiosity if you remove drop shadows and anything else considered a bitmap pixel shader does the issue persist?